# Is there an R function to help me plot the network connections for a single node?

Tags: r, neural-network

This is my original dataset. R1,R2 and R3 are word association responses for the cue word. tf and df are total and document frequency of the cue word, respectively.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpfZy.png [Image shows original dataframe}

I have cleaned up a dataset into a nodes list and an edge list. I have over a million rows in both lists. Plotting this as a network graph would take too long, and also be very dense, i.e. not understandable.

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfSfN.png [Image shows node-list]

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Eu.png [Image shows edge-list]

I want to be able to make a network graph for the cue words, such that upon entering a cue word, I get a network of words that are either responses to it, or are words that the cue word is a response for.

For example, I want to see all the connections for the word 'money'. Using **filter(nword == "money")** only shows the node 'money' as an output, but I want all nodes connected to the cue word (in this case, 'money').

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bKrr.png [Image shows filter()]

Is there a function or a chunk of code that would help me resolve this issue?

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 17 |
| 1 | 18 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 38 |
| 1 | 67 |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 82736 |
| 2 | 88035 |
| 2 | 103428 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 27 |
| 3 | 45 |

| node_id | nword | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | money | 13633 |
| 2 | food | 12338 |
| 3 | water | 12276 |
| 4 | car | 8907 |
| 5 | music | 8351 |
| 6 | green | 7890 |
| 7 | red | 7623 |
| 8 | love | 7406 |
| 9 | sex | 6552 |
| 10 | happy | 6432 |
| 11 | cold | 6333 |
| 12 | bad | 6132 |
| 13 | sad | 5958 |
| 14 | dog | 5940 |
| 15 | white | 5910 |
| 16 | school | 5832 |
| 17 | fun | 5594 |
| 18 | time | 5467 |
| 19 | black | 5233 |
| 20 | hair | 5219 |

Comment: You could use `igraph::distances` to identify the nodes connected to the word you want, and then filter on that.  If you need more detail, you'll have to provide some usable sample data - images aren't very helpful!

Comment: Please, when asking share a sample of the data (or any fake data) so we're able to better help you.

Comment: I've added some sample data. Do let me know if it's enough/alright. This is my first time posting on StackOverflow so I'm a bit unsure.